# Dynamically generating a button using DOM and editing onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, dom, input, appendchild

I trying to generate an input (type="button") and setting the onclick-Event to a function, which should hand over a parameter. The whole object should be appended to a div and thats it. Basically [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vogti/yzeVm/) is my try, but I can't see why it does not work.

I pasted the code to jsfiddle, hence its easier for you to reproduce. Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vogti/yzeVm/).

What am I'm doing wrong? I'm learning it by trial and error, so please explain whats wrong. Thanks a lot!

[edit] for the case jsfiddle will be down one day, here is the code I tried to run... :)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>onclick event example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var i = 0;
var h = new Array();

function addButton() {
    i++;
    var container = document.getElementById("check0");

    var h[i] = document.createElement("input");
    h[i].type = 'button';
    h[i].name = 'number' + i;
    h[i].value = "number" + i;
    h[i].id = 'number' + i;

    h[i].onclick = function() {
        showAlert(i)
    };

    container.appendChild(h[i]);
}

function showAlert(number) {
    alert("You clicked Button " + number);
}​
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="check0">
        <input type="button" value="klick mich" id="number0" onclick="addButton()"/>
</div>​
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put the code in there. What if jsfiddle's down tomorrow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/yzeVm/2/) is the fixed fiddle for you.

- `var h[i] = ...` is invalid JavaScript.
- What you write in the "JavaScript" frame on jsfiddle is executed `onload`, so this code is not yet present when the HTML you provide is executed (and neither is the `addButton()` function).

  ```
  <script>
  var i = 0;
  var h = new Array();

  function addButton() {
      i++;
      var container = document.getElementById("check0");

      h[i] = document.createElement("input");
      h[i].type = 'button';
      h[i].name = 'number' + i;
      h[i].value = "number" + i;
      h[i].id = 'number' + i;

      h[i].onclick = function() {
          showAlert(i)
      };

      container.appendChild(h[i]);
  }

  function showAlert(number) {
      alert("You clicked Button " + number);
  }
  </script>

  <div id="check0">
      <input type="button" value="klick mich" id="number0" onclick="addButton()"/>
  </div>​
  ```

Comment: If jsfiddle is down, the entire question will not make any sense :) Let me try...

Comment: Yep, I added a comment to the question too :-)

Comment: Alexander, in [your fix](http://jsfiddle.net/yzeVm/2/) is still a closure issue, note that all the buttons alerts the last index. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/yzeVm/4/) is a modified version with a closure around the alert function

Comment: @GabrielJürgens: yeah, thanks for the fix. I just made the code run with no JS errors reported and didn't go beyond that.

Comment: @GabrielJürgens could you please explain your fix? I see what you have changed, but actually don't understand what happens there...

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov thank you very much for your quick response. I should have seen the "var [i] = ..." thing - but I was just to blind... :)
Furthermore I did not know about the onload behavior of jsfiddle. Thanks for this hint!

Comment: @vogti, what I did, is commonly called a **closure**, and as you can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/111111/1382292), you are not alone wondering how they work. For me, is very difficult to explain colsures in a couple words, and my english is not as good as I need, so I recommend you read the link I gave you above, but basically the problem is that you need to freeze the value of `i` passed to `showAlert` at the time of the `h[i].onclick` is declared, because if you don't, all the `onclick` of the dynamically generated buttons, will pass the last value of the goblal `var i`.

Comment: @GabrielJürgens Thank you for your explanation. I'm going to study the link you gave!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `h.push(...)` instead of trying to send to a non created element in the array

Answer (score 0):

```
          var x = document.getElementById('pagination');//pagination is an empty div in html
    var y ='';
    for(var i = 0; i <= (pageMax); i++){
        y = y+"<a id ='pageNumber"+i+"' onclick='changePage("+(i+1)+");'>"+(i+1)+"</a>\n ";
        } x.innerHTML=y }
```

i used this to make a pagination for a table. The function will create a row of numbers until button max. 'changePage("+(i+1)+"); ...  will call a function and send the i index(number that the page is) of the pagenumber. also i dynamically create a id unique for each number.